ESXi - Cannot delete datastore folder
I was uploading a Ubuntu ISO file to datastore in a lab environment and power failed and corrupted the folder.
I can't delete the folder anymore and I can't upload anything to that folder either.

Any idea how to remove or fix this folder?

Datastore is working fine when I create a different folder and upload images to it. Only the "ISO" folder is corrupted.

The volume isn't even mounted correctly. You should reformat the volume or, if that doesn't work, remove the volume from storage, remove the partition from the disk and then recreate it.
You should consider hooking the host up to a UPS, even in a lab.

If I create a new folder in datastore then I can upload anything to it. Its just that the "ISO" folder is corrupted. Volume is mounted correctly if other folders work right?
